# Grid data is not refreshed in Kendo for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

[In this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/hAOhNPp8lBRVXU3lMjpa?p=preview) I have a Kendo for Angular grid that uses the `kendoGridBinding` directive to bind the data in memory.

What I need to do is to manipulate the data model and reflect each insert/update/delete in the grid.

For example, in the plunk there's a button that if you click it it will remove from `dataGrid` the first row, but that change is not reflected in the grid. I found in the documentation a [notifydatachange](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/DataBindingDirective/#toc-notifydatachange) statement, however it does not work (as you can see in the plunk). How to make the grid refresh the data?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-grid #grid
            [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
            [pageSize]="4"
            [pageable]="true">
            <kendo-grid-column field="CompanyName" [width]="140"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ContactName" [width]="120"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="City" [width]="100"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ContactTitle" [width]="130"></kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
        <button (click)="delFirst()">delete first row</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild('grid') grid: GridBinding;

    public gridData: any[] = customers;

    delFirst() {
      this.gridData.splice(0,1);
      this.grid.notifyDataChange();
      alert("First row deleted");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update the binding directive then you should set a new instance:

```
delFirst() {
    this.gridData.splice(0,1);
    this.gridData = this.gridData.slice(0);
}
```

or

```
delFirst() {
    this.gridData = this.gridData.slice(1);
}
```

Otherwise, angular will not detect a change and will not update the directive.

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the data back to the grid, change it as,

```
delFirst() {
      this.gridData = this.gridData.slice(1);
 }
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mt9ERdopweJtaTObyQ5F?p=preview)**